# I'm using react-hook-form to validate my input but I can't get it to work after extracting the input to its own component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a Form.js component which returns a form element. This form element contains a FormGroup component which takes props such as inputType, inputName, inputPlaceholder and in return renders an input field with a label. I am using react-hook-form for the validation of the input but I can't get it to work after extracting the input to a separate component. In my original code, I had my errors appear when the validation failed, but after extracting the label and input into their own component, this stopped working.

My original working code looks like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import FormGroup from './FormGroup';

const Form = () => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    };

    return (
        <form className="form-container" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} autoComplete="off" noValidate>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="form-label" htmlFor="firstName">
                    <p>First Name</p>
                    <p className="input-error">{errors.firstName && errors.firstName.message}</p>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" {...register("firstName", { required: 'Required ' })} />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}

export default Form
```

Then I changed it to:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import FormGroup from './FormGroup';

const Form = () => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    };

    return (
        <form className="form-container" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} autoComplete="off" noValidate>
            <FormGroup
                inputType="text"
                inputName="firstName"
                inputPlaceholder="First Name">
            </FormGroup>

            <div className="form-group">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}

export default Form
```

And I extracted the label and input into:

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const FormGroup = (props) => {
    const { register, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="form-label" htmlFor={props.inputName}>
                <p>{ props.inputPlaceholder }</p>
                <p className="input-error">{errors.firstName && errors.firstName.message}</p>
            </label>
            <input type={props.inputType} name={props.inputName} placeholder={props.inputPlaceholder} {...register(props.inputName, { required: true })} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default FormGroup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Problem

You have multiple instances of the `useForm` hook.

#### Solution

Use the `useForm` hook only on the `Form` component and pass the `errors` object and `register` method as props to `FormGroup`

#### Form Component

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import FormGroup from './FormGroup';

const Form = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form
      className="form-container"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      autoComplete="off"
      noValidate
    >
      <FormGroup
        inputType="text"
        inputName="firstName"
        inputPlaceholder="First Name"
        register={register}
        errors={errors}
      ></FormGroup>

      <div className="form-group">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

#### FormGroup Component

```js
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const FormGroup = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="form-label" htmlFor={props.inputName}>
        <p>{props.inputPlaceholder}</p>
        <p className="input-error">
          {props.errors.firstName && props.errors.firstName.message}
        </p>
      </label>
      <input
        type={props.inputType}
        name={props.inputName}
        placeholder={props.inputPlaceholder}
        {...props.register(props.inputName, { required: true })}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormGroup;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Worked like a charm.

Comment: this solution works... but it is not the correct approach...  See my answer below based on the documentation, you should be using FormContext so you don't have to pass register information as a property - https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext

Answer (score 3):

The recommended approach from the Documentation is as follows:

> **useFormContext** This custom hook allows you to access the form context. useFormContext is intended to be used in deeply nested structures, where it would become inconvenient to pass the context as a prop.
> https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext

```
const Form = () => {
  const methods = useForm();
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = methods;

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods} > 
      <form
        className="form-container"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        autoComplete="off"
        noValidate
      >
        <FormGroup
          inputType="text"
          inputName="firstName"
          inputPlaceholder="First Name">
        </FormGroup>

        <div className="form-group">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
};
```

```
const FormGroup = (props) => {
  const { register, errors } = useFormContext(); // retrieve all hook methods from parent
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="form-label" htmlFor={props.inputName}>
        <p>{props.inputPlaceholder}</p>
        <p className="input-error">
          {errors.firstName && errors.firstName.message}
        </p>
      </label>
      <input
        type={props.inputType}
        name={props.inputName}
        placeholder={props.inputPlaceholder}
        {register(props.inputName, { required: true })}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormGroup;
```

Comment: Does this still valid with the current version (7.9.0)? I can't destruct errors out of `useFormContext();`. Thanks

Comment: i cannot get Errors to populate on useFormContext using latest (7.9) either.

Comment: I face the same issue as @a2ron44